# C# HttpClient times out when using remote proxy, but works when using local proxy (Fiddler) that is upstream chained to the same remote proxy

Tags: c#, fiddler, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to use HttpClient via a proxy:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler {UseProxy = true, Proxy = new WebProxy("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6762")};
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler) {Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)};
```

With the 3 second timeout defined in the code, requests sent via this httpClient time out. Through experimentation, I have found that I need to set the timeout to at least 30 seconds for the requests to complete. So you'd think the proxy is just being slow, right?

EXCEPT: if I run Fiddler locally and set the httpClientHandler to use "localhost:8888" (Fiddler's port) and then in turn chain Fiddler to use THE SAME proxy upstream (like in picture below), the requests come back nearly instantaneously.

What could explain such behavior?

[image: Fiddler upstream proxy configuration]

EDIT: I should also mention that the requests I am making while seeing this behavior are all HTTPS. I know Fiddler inserts its own certificate into the certificate path, so maybe that is somehow part of the explanation, but I am not knowledgeable enough to put all the pieces together.

Comment: Is the requested URL HTTP or HTTPS? May be the external Proxy is a bit outdated and does not allow current security protocols like TLS 1.2? Fiddler however by default allows SSLv3 with SSL decryption enabled.

Comment: Yeah, I just made an edit a few minutes before you posted your comments clarifying that I am making HTTPS requests -- I had a hunch that it is somehow related. Your explanation provides a little bit more of a clue. So why would an older protocol be slower?

Comment: Slower? You wrote there is a time-out and time-out means it does not work at all. In total you should just use Wireshark and monitor the outgoing traffic to the proxy. Then you should see the difference.

Comment: I probably should've phrased it better. What I was trying to say that with the 3 second timeout setting on the httpclient it times out, so I have to bump it up to 30 in order to get the response. When going through Fiddler the response comes back instantaneously.

Comment: As I wrote: use wireshark and look if there are differences regarding the SSL/TLS handshake and if you can detect anything when the delay occurs.

Comment: Thanks, will try that.

Comment: What does your HTTP request code look like? See http://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app- for one explanation of a problem we've seen.

Comment: An extremely helpful link, Eric! If you'd like to post it as an answer rather than comment, I will mark is as accepted. Thank you!